# Flutter – push notifications not working in the background when app is killed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, notifications

I'm trying to build a real time chat app.

I have integrated https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications package for push notifications and this works.

I am NOT using Firebase, i am using my own custom backend that uses https://socket.io/ for real time chatting.

I want to receive a push notification when the user sends a chat message. Push notifications work when the app is in foreground or background. However when i terminate my app from the process (app is killed), the push notifications no longer work.

Is there a way to send push notifications without using Firebase so that i can receive notifications even when my app has been terminated from the process? I need this to work both for android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I don't recommend any solution for push notifications instead of firebase.

But if you have your reasons to use socket in this case I suggest you take a look into this package how it uses background service and tries to implement your own way to setup socket-based notification background service.

https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator

Comment: I have just tried Firebase, however the messages i send via firebase messaging have EXTREME delays. I have to wait 10-15 minutes to receive a push notification in a real time chat application? This is unacceptable. Thank you for your suggestion